# Non-noob way to fetch data in Laravel with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm rebuilding an application in Laravel and currently use the following code, I guess this would be called AJAX.

```js
$('.date').change(function () {
    var date = $('.date').val();
    $('#date_summary').html(date);
    if (date == "") {
        $('#date_summary').html('Choose your service date...');
    } else if ($.trim(date) !== '') {
        $.get('/calendar.php', {
            date: date
        }, function (data) {
            var data = data.toString();
            $('#date_data').html(data);
        });
    }
});
$('.calendar').trigger('change');
```

To fetch this code:

```php
if ( isset($_GET['date']) === true && empty($_GET['date']) === false ) {
    global $db;
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $query = "select * from appointments where Day = :date";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':date', $date);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetch();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $eight_to_nine = $result['8AM_9AM'];
    $nine_to_ten = $result['9AM_10AM'];
    $ten_to_eleven = $result['10AM_11AM'];
    $eleven_to_twelve = $result['11AM_12PM'];
    $twelve_to_one = $result['12PM_1PM'];
    $one_to_two = $result['1PM_2PM'];
    $two_to_three = $result['2PM_3PM'];
    $three_to_four = $result['3PM_4PM'];
    $four_to_five = $result['4PM_5PM'];
    $five_to_six = $result['5PM_6PM'];
    $six_to_seven = $result['6PM_7PM'];

    if ($eight_to_nine != 1) {
        echo "<option value='8AM_9AM'>8:00AM - 9:00AM</option>";
    }

    if ($nine_to_ten != 1) {
        echo "<option value='9AM_10AM'>9:00AM - 10:00AM</option>";
    }

    if ($ten_to_eleven != 1) {
        echo "<option value='10AM_11AM'>10:00AM - 11:00AM</option>";
    }

    if ($eleven_to_twelve != 1) {
        echo "<option value='11AM_12PM'>11:00AM - 12:00PM</option>";
    }

    if ($twelve_to_one != 1) {
        echo "<option value='12PM_1PM'>12:00PM - 1:00PM</option>";
    }

    if ($one_to_two != 1) {
        echo "<option value='1PM_2PM'>1:00PM - 2:00PM</option>";
    }

    if ($two_to_three != 1) {
        echo "<option value='2PM_3PM'>2:00PM - 3:00PM</option>";
    }

    if ($three_to_four != 1) {
        echo "<option value='3PM_4PM'>3:00PM - 4:00PM</option>";
    }

    if ($four_to_five != 1) {
        echo "<option value='4PM_5PM'>4:00PM - 5:00PM</option>";
    }

    if ($five_to_six != 1) {
        echo "<option value='5PM_6PM'>5:00PM - 6:00PM</option>";
    }

    if ($six_to_seven != 1) {
        echo "<option value='6PM_7PM'>6:00PM - 7:00PM</option>";
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a more elegant way to do this in Laravel? I'm just trying to implement what are considered best practices. Off the top of my head, I think this would be considered something like an API? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using routes, controllers, views? this code seems like so far from laravel

Comment: You're right it's plain PHP but I want to move it to Laravel

Comment: you have to show us what have you tried to do at least

Comment: You're right, I should not be so lazy and try before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about a better way to do this in Laravel, then surely configuring API will be a prominent way to do that.

Simply configure API routes, and in the Controller method use the Laravel Eloquent ORMs to have the Database transactions.

Then finally call the routes in your AJAX request and wait for the response. Then do the final operations based on the returned response from Laravel.